# How to get all facebook pages id associated with my account?

Tags: facebook

I want to get the statistics of all the pages associated with my account on facebook, i have the code to get the statistics of a page, i just want to get the page id of all the pages  associated with my account, how can i do this?
Please help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to request the `manage_pages` permission ([more details here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/)), once you have the aquired the permission, all you have to do is make a request to :
`https://graph.facebook.com/YOUR_FACEBOOK_ID/accounts`.
The return value will be a JSON with all the pages/applications that are associated with your account.
You can also use this great tool that facebook provides - [The Graph API Explorer (/me/accounts)](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%2Faccounts) to explore what other information you can retrieve without having to write a single line of code :P very useful.

Comment: I edited the answer to include the missing information... you'll need the `manage_pages` permission to see the accounts associated with the user.

Answer (score 0):

```
    FB.api('/me/accounts', function(response) {
        for (id in response.data)
        {
            page = data[id];
            page.id;
            page.name;
        }           

    });
```

You can use Javascript API to do this, read more :http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/